# Database with English words with grammatical classification?

Tags: english, language

Is there open database with English words with grammatical classification?

I mean the list of words, with the information, which part of speech this word is (f.e. verb, noun, pronoun etc.).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are plenty of open corpora (databases) of English words available.
Specifically, take a look at [Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus) and [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu).

Check out [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.org) it is written in Python and has those corpora available for download. It is one of the most popular packages to work with human languages data.

If you prefer to use web based API, take a look at [Wordnik API](http://developer.wordnik.com)